# How do inputdialog buttons work. I thought they were the same as confirmdialog

Tags: java, netbeans

I am writing some code to bring up the input dialog and then read through the dialog to create a txt file for saves. Sadly I haven't gotten that far. I generaly know how the input dialog thing works but the problem is that I want it to trigger when the user presses ok. And dismiss the window if he presses cancel or exit.

Here is the code:

```
    private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    if (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "Save as?", "Save as?", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)   {
 //continue code

}

}
```

This thing brings an error in neatbeans that I want to mix String and int. The problem is I don't know where. I also tried saving the whole Joptionpane in a String but that brought up even more problems.
If someone could tell me how to trigger code when the ok button is pressed that would be awesome.

I thought it worked the same way as the yes no option. Code:

```
    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "HAVE FUN!", "Tutorial",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
    }
```

But it look's like I was wrong.
Thank you for all the replies!

Comment: Just read the javadoc. That's what it's for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-. It says: *Returns:
    user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input*.

Answer (score 0):

showInputDialog returns a String that the user inputs or null if cancel or exit are pressed.
showConfirmDialog returns a option which indicates which button was pressed but the message it shows is a object meaning you can give it a panel to display.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Input bla bla"));
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    panel.add(textField);

    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Tutorial",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField.getText());
    }
    else{
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what od I need to call in order to get the text that was writen?

Comment: textField.getText() 
And textField is the field you use in the display panel.
Try out the example I wrote you.